# EF 6 Tries to insert an object twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm new using Entity Framework, and we are triyng to addapt our application with an architecture using EF6 model first.
I have a class like that (I have simplified the code to explain better):

```
class Country
{
 int CountryId (identity column) { get; set; }
 string Name { get; set; }
 ICollection<Child> Regions { get; set; }
}

class Region
{
 int RegionId (identity column) { get; set; }
 string Name { get; set; }
 int CountryId { get ; set; } //foreign key to Country(CountryId)
}
```

In a Business Layer in the application we initialize the object  Region like that:

```
public Region Create()
{
 Provincia Region = new Region ();
 provincia.Country = CountryDAL.GetByCode("ES");
 provincia.CountryId = Region.Country.CountryId ;

 return Region ;
}
```

CountryDAL is the layer that load a Country from the DB.
When i try to saveChanges i have an Unique contraint exception from the DB beacause EF tries to insert the Country twice. i can't understand why

```
this.context.Entry(entity).State = Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
entity.AcceptChanges(user);
int Result = this.context.SaveChanges();
```

I only want to Save the entity Region with his property CountryId filled, i dont want to save The Country as a new object. 
However, In other View i should be able to create a Country and save their countries as childs (but this is another problem that i have solved).

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you would like to save it, do you need to add it to the context? You can just save it (if it is attached) or attach it to a context that does not track it?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I dont understand it. Can you explain it? Do you refer to the line "this.context.Entry(entity).State = Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;"

Comment: Yes. I am not an expert on EF, but if you would like save an entity you have to attach it (if its not already) or directly call `SaveChanges()`. `Add()` is more like an INSERT in the DB. If it eaxist in your DB, but not your context then calling `Add()` does not give harm to your context, however inserting an existing item to your database is an error. I use `Add()` and `Data.Entity.EntityState.Added:` transitively.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that your code doesn't compile. You have errors in Create() method. There is type Region and you use it as name of variable.

Secondly, you asssign both navigation property (Country) and foreign key value (CountryId) in create method. You can just assign a CountryId property. So, in my opinion, this should work:

```
public Region Create()
{
    var country = CountryDAL.GetByCode("ES");
    Region provincia = new Region();
    provincia.CountryId = country.CountryId;

    return Region;
}
```

I also recommend you to not loading all Country entity. Instead of it, create a query that returns only id of country based on "ES" string.